# Applying proxy object instead of array in MobX-React store

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm here trying to refactor a working app I made which get events from a Database (in order to be later displayed on a scheduler).

So here I am using an @observable events variable in which I'm setting an array I get using a POST request to my database.

But when I'm later trying to show in console what is now in my variable, instead of the array of strings I should have, I now have a Proxy object...

Can someone help me to understand what should I do in order to get back my array instead of the Proxy object ?

Thanks in advance !

PS : here's a bunch of the code

```
@observable events = [];

loadAgendaData = (event) => {
    let viewModel = new SchedulerData('2017-12-18', ViewTypes.Week, false, false, {});

    axios.post('http://localhost:5002/api/getCreneaux', {
        id_grpe: event.value
    }).then((res) => {
        res.data.forEach((element) => {
            element.start = moment.unix(element.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            element.end = moment.unix(element.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        })
        viewModel.setEvents(res.data)

        console.log(res.data); // this shows the Array

        this.events = res.data; // giving this.events the value of the array
    })

}

anotherFunction = (event) => {
    console.log(events); // this unfortunately shows a Proxy object
}
```

Comment: You could use [toJS](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/tojson.html) ? for example: `console.log(toJS(events))`

Comment: Alright so it does work for my array ! But if I put my array into an object and I use toJS(thisObject) it does not work.... Do you know how can one use this method recursively ?